# Run Flask Restplus APIs through Gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, flask-restplus

I have a sample Flask-RestPlus application as **myapp.py**:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Resource, API

API = Api(version='1.0', title='my_routes')
MY_NAMESPACE = API.namespace('v1.0/routes', description='v1.0 routes')


def initialize():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    API.init_app(app)
    API.add_namespace(MY_NAMESPACE)
    return app

@MY_NAMESPACE.route('/hello')
class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'hello': 'world'}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MY_ROUTE = initialize()
    MY_ROUTE.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

This works fine if I am running ***python myapp.py***. Since I want to run to run this code on production, I want to use Gunicorn. I have gunicorn installed on my UNIX machine. Sample code from https://gunicorn.org/ works perfectly fine. How do I run code in my case? I tried:

```
gunicorn -w 4 myapp:initialize
gunicorn -w 4 "myapp:initialize()"
gunicorn -w 4 myapp:main
```

But none of them worked. Do I have to make some changes in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **myapp.py**, turn your part:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MY_ROUTE = initialize()
    MY_ROUTE.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

into:

```
app = initialize() # app has to be accessible outside if

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

and then run

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 --workers 4 myapp:app --log-level debug
```

if you want to run in production mode, specify `--log-level info`.